# How can i use Data of a url to show as an option in dropdown?

Tags: angular, get, dropdown

Here i have a url which has a arrayList of data.Now i have to do is i need to fetch the data from this url to show as an option in dropdown and select the one needed.I Know it can be done by using Get method but i am not able to do it.Please help me with this.I hope i am clear with my doubt if there is confusion please let me know.

```
url:https://api.myjson.com/bins/l8asa
```

This is the url provided..need to fetch the details of this url in dropdown menu.
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Please share some code of whatever you have tried.

Comment: You can find in official docs: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Answer (score 0):

Though from your question it is not clear what you actually want to do,but I tried to guess .See if it can help.
Store the response of the url into a variable then in template(html) use for loop.

**Components.ts**

```
 res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.data = res;
  }
```

**Component.html**

```
<tr  *ngFor="let i of data;" mdbTableCol ><td style="float:left">
<a class="dropdown-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect><strong>{{ i.classid }}</strong> 
</a>
<a class="dropdown-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect><strong>{{ i.url }}</strong></a>
 </td>
 </tr>
```